# Hide the hud of StarCraft II during play

Tags: starcraft-2

I need to hide the hud of StarCraft II during play so I can take screenshots of the full play ground. How I can do that?

Answer (score 5):

You can only hide the UI during active game play if you are the observer or watching a replay file, not if you are the active player. The key command to do this is Ctrl+W.

If you are just trying to take screenshots of the map itself you can also do this from outside the game by opening up the map in the Starcraft 2 map editor.

Comment: If you have to take screenshots during a live match, the only practical solution I can think of is to run a separate instance of SC2 as a spectator/referee in your match.

Comment: That would also require a second account.

Comment: It would be much easier to watch the games' replay later and take the screenshots there.

Comment: The question was about taking hud-less screenshots "during play". I agree that my suggestion would require a second account, and a sandboxed instance of SC2 (somewhat of a pain to set everything up), and yes it would be much easier to use a replay.

Comment: Yeah, the only way to take screen shots like that would either to watch it in a replay after you already played or use the map editor.